# How to synchronize mysql databases on multiple computers?

Tags: mysql, database

In my case I have a main server with 3 databases: bdA, bdB, bdC.

Then I have 3 secondary servers: sA, sB, sC.

The sA server only has the bdA and should only be synchronized with it. Changes in sA should be reflected in the main server's bdA in the same way that the changes made to the main server's bdA must be reflected in the sA.

Similarly the sB should only be synchronized with the database bdB and the sC should only be synchronized with the database bdC.

Is it possible to use mysql circular replication for this purpose?

If not, is there any other way to achieve this goal?

Thank you

Comment: If there's no link between any of the main servers, it sounds like simple replication x 3.

Comment: the links are between main server and sA for bdA, main server and sB for bdB, main server and sC for bdC. In main server all db's are in the same instance and I don't know how to configure 3 replications.

Comment: Replicating Different Databases to Different Slaves: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-solutions-partitioning.html

Comment: Thank's Steve. Do you know if is it possible to update the main server data when the sA data chanches?

Comment: If the sX servers are not slaves, you'll need master-master replication.  This any help?: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.5. I think this version doesn'y support multiple masters for one slave (in my case the main server would be the slave and the other servers would be masters). I the only solution I find is to implement an script changing the master of the main server evey x seconds.